# When is a P-space the set of P-points of a compact Hausdorff space?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space. A point $x\in X$ is a P-point if every countable intersection of open neighbourhoods of $x$ is a neighbourhood of $x$, and $X$ is a
P-space if every point is P-point, equivalently if every countable intersection of open sets is open.

The set of P-points in a compact Hausdorff space is thus a completely regular P-space. My question is: is every completely regular P-space equal to the set of P-points of some compact Hausdorff space?

If not, is there a characterisation of those completely regular P-spaces which are equal to the set of P-points of some compact Hausdorff space?

Example: a countable discrete set $N$ is a P-space and is equal to the set of P-points of its one-point compactification $N\cup\{\infty\}$.

Sub-question: is every completely regular P-space $X$ equal to the set of P-points of its Stone-Cech compactification $\beta X$?

Comment: Have you looked at $\beta X$?

Comment: Just wondering about it now. If $X$ is locally compact and $\sigma$-compact then there are no new P-points in $\beta X$, but non-discrete P-spaces are never locally compact.

Comment: If $X$ is a P-space then the zero sets are just the clopen sets, so one is in a Boolean-algebra-type context for $\beta X$.

Comment: In the definition of P-point it should certainly be only required that a countable intersection of (open) neighbourhoods of $x$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ (but not necessarily open). Otherwise an isolated point would be P-point, only if the space is P-space.

Comment: Thanks. Corrected that definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a complete answer for the sub question:

Let $X$ be completely regular.

1. If $X$ is realcompact and $x_0$ is a P-point of $\beta X$, then $x_0 \in X$.

*Proof:*
Assume $x_0 \notin X$. Then there is a continuous
$h: \beta X \rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $h(x_0) = 0$ and $h(x) > 0$ for any $x \in X$
(Engelking, General Topology, Theorem 3.11.10).
Since $x_0$ is P-point, there is an open $U$ such that
$x_0 \in U \subseteq \bigcap_{n \in \textbf{N}} h^{-1} ([0, \frac{1}{n}[)$.
Hence there is an $x \in U \cap X \Rightarrow h(x) = 0$. Contradiction!

2. Let $X$ be a P-space. Then:
   $X$ is realcompact $\Leftrightarrow$  $X = \{x \in \beta X: x$  P-point in $ \beta X\}$

*Proof:*
"$\Rightarrow$":  "$\subseteq$":  Each P-point of $X$ is P-point in $\beta X$, since $X$ is dense in $\beta X$.
"$\supseteq$":  1.  
"$\Leftarrow$":
By Engelking, General Topology, Theorem 3.11.11 we have to show that an ultrafilter $\mathfrak{F}_0$ in
the zero-sets of $X$, which has the countable intersection property, has non-empty intersection.
Since in a P-space each zero-set is clopen, hence the complement is zero-set again, and each countable intersection of zero-sets is a zero-set,
it is easy to see that in fact each countable intersection of $\mathfrak{F}_0$ is an element of $\mathfrak{F}_0$. 
Now consider the standard construction of the Cech-Stone compactification
$\beta X = \{\mathfrak{F}: \mathfrak{F}$ zero-set ultrafilter in $X$}.
Since complements of zero-sets are zero-sets,
$\{ [A] : A$ is zero-set in $X \}$ is a (clopen) base of $\beta X$, where
$[A] := \{ \mathfrak{F} \in \beta X: A \in \mathfrak{F} \}$.   
$\mathfrak{F}_0$ *is P-point in* $\beta X$:
Let $(U_n)_{n \in \textbf{N}}$ be a sequence of neighbourhoods of $\mathfrak{F}_0$.
Then for each $n$ pick a zero-set $A_n$ of $X$ such that
$\mathfrak{F}_0 \in [A_n] \subseteq U_n$.
As stated above, $A := \bigcap_{n \in \textbf{N}} A_n \in \mathfrak{F}_0$.
Hence $\mathfrak{F}_0 \in [A] \subseteq  \bigcap_{n \in \textbf{N}} [A_n] \subseteq \bigcap_{n \in \textbf{N}} U_n$
and $[A]$ is open. 
By the prerequisite, $\mathfrak{F}_0 \in X$, hence  $\bigcap \mathfrak{F}_0 = \{x\}$ for some $x \in X$.

Notes

1. Of course, this also gives an affirmative answer to the original question in case $X$ is realcompact.
2. But there are non-realcompact P-spaces, for instance:  
   a) any discrete space of measurable cardinality 
   b) Example 9L in the book of
   [Gillman, Jerison](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.b4407145&view=1up&seq=152&q1=9L),
   which is $\{\alpha < \omega_2:$  cf $(\alpha) \neq \omega\}$.
   Hence, this provides a ZFC counter-example to the sub question.

By the above, for these spaces $\beta X$ does not provide the required compactification.
But for a), the one-point compactification of the discrete space does the job.
However, in b) $\omega_2$ is a new P-point in the "obvious" compactification
$\omega_2 + 1$. Hence, this *might be* a candidate for a counter-example also of the original question.

Comment: Thanks for this, I will need to digest it. For Example 9L that you mention in 2b), if $\omega_2$ is the only new P-point in $\omega_2+1$ then you can either tag on a copy of the unit interval at $\omega_2$, or else take a quotient, identifying $\omega_2$ with one of the points of countable cofinality. Either way should yield a compact space with the space of Example 9L as its set of P-points.

Comment: If I understood correctly, your first space is $Z := \omega_2 \dot\cup [0,1]$ with the order topology, where the linear order is defined by extending the usual orders on $\omega_2$ and $[0,1]$ and $\alpha < x$ for each $\alpha \in \omega_2$ and $x \in [0,1]$. Of course, $Z$ is compact, and certainly P-points in $Z$ are exactly the points of X. But $X$ is not dense in $Z$. True, you didn't require this.
Somehow, I have the strong feeling that you can always do something like this, e.g. $\beta X \times [0,1]$ has no P-points at all.
Therefore, shouldn't density be an additional requirement?

Comment: My original interest was simply that I could show that a certain set could coincide with the set of P-points of any compact Hausdorff space, and I wondered if this was the same as any completely regular P-space. So density did not matter for that question. But now that the subject is developing a bit, we have the further sub-question of whether every completely regular P-space is the set of P-points of one of its compactifications. Since you have already given a significant answer which I have accepted, I think I should re-post this question.

Comment: I need to look closer on your second space (but have no time before weekend), but at first glance this should be a compactification with same P-points, indeed. Very interesting!

Comment: I have re-posted this question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3849142/when-is-a-tychonoff-p-space-the-set-of-p-points-of-a-compact-hausdorff-space

Answer (score 2):

The sub-question might not be true: 
Let $X$ be discrete, $\beta X$ be represented by the set of all ultrafilters on $X$. Then it is easy to see that an ultrafilter $\mathfrak{F}$ is a P-point in $\beta X$, iff $\mathfrak{F}$ has the countable intersection property.
Hence, if $X$ is of measurable cardinality, then $X$ does not equal the set of P-points of $\beta X$.
However, this does not provide a counter-example to the original question (consider the one-point compactification of the discrete space).  
Vice versa, if there does not exist a measurable cardinal, then the sub-question holds at least for discrete spaces.

Comment: Thanks for this. What happens if one takes $X$ to be the set of P-points in $\omega_1$ (the first uncountable ordinal)? Then the new point in $\beta \omega_1=\omega_1+1$ is a P-point, so it seems likely that there will be a P-point among the new points in $\beta X$ as well.

Comment: The P-points in $\omega_1$ are exactly the successor ordinals (and $0$), i.e. the isolated points. Hence $X$ is just a discrete space. I guess the situation is much more interesting for $\omega_2$, which provides a non-realcompact P-space, compare [here](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.b4407145&view=1up&seq=152&q1=9L). In fact, I wouldn't be surprised if then $\beta X$ contains new P-points, hence providing a counter-example to the sub question in ZFC. But again, this is no counter-example to the original question, since $\omega_2 + 1$ would do the job.