# When is a Tychonoff P-space the set of P-points of a compact Hausdorff space?

Tags: general-topology

(This question is a re-post of [When is a P-space the set of P-points of a compact Hausdorff space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3836535/when-is-a-p-space-the-set-of-p-points-of-a-compact-hausdorff-space) because a sub-question in that post received a substantial answer which I accepted).

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space. A point $x\in X$ is a P-point if every countable intersection of open neighbourhoods of $x$ is a neighbourhood of $x$, and $X$ is a
P-space if every point is P-point, equivalently if every countable intersection of open sets is open.

The set of P-points in a compact Hausdorff space is thus a Tychonoff P-space.

**Question:** is every Tychonoff P-space equal to the set of P-points of some compact Hausdorff space?

(The sub-question was: is every Tychonoff P-space $X$ equal to the set of P-points of its Cech-Stone compactification $\beta X$. The answer is that this holds if and only if $X$ is realcompact. But there are non-realcompact Tychonoff P-spaces...)

A new sub-question which cropped up in the earlier discussion is whether every Tychonoff P-space is equal to the set of P-points of one of its compactifications?